# RPM spec files with rpmbuild can have errors

Tags: build, redhat, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Every time I try to make my own spec file and build it, I get an error like this:

many lines on the screen of the build starting...

```
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ cd foobar
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.dN7L6s: line 35: cd: foobar: No such file or directory
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.dN7L6s (%prep)
```

I've noticed that "foobar" is the name of the package in the line with the %setup under the prep section of the spec file (foobar.spec).  But I don't know what to do with this problem that keeps happening.  What can I do to make a spec file work and not have this error?  I have tried installing three different packages and re-writing the spec files.  But I always get this error.

What file formats are permissible for the source file in the spec file?  bz2? tar.gz?  I know .tar.gz is ok.

If the source is not on an FTP server or on a website, what can you do to make the .spec file work?  I have the source file local to the server.  In very secure environments, you wouldn't have access to the Internet or an FTP server.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with specifying a build subdir.

See options for %setup, including -n (if the name in tar ball is different) and -c/-a/-b (if the build subduer needs to be created before untar'ing)

All file paths that exist are permitted in SourceN: directives, but only the basename is used. Compression and unarchiving is usually handled automatically (but %setup options are needed to handle naming issues).